# Program execution sequence in Linux

Tags: linux, execution

If start two programs like below (first one in background and second in foreground)

program1 &
program2

How much of program1 be executed before program2 is started? Does the main of program1 will be started before switching to program2? I am using Linux.
gl

Comment: It's quite hardware dependent and dependent of the usage of the computer at the moment that the program is launched. It's probably impossible to tell. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. it depends on what these programs doing and the environment of yours.

'main' is not the entrance of a executable program.
if it use up the time slice before finish initialize code and start 'main', it will be switched out.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the scheduler and the type of system (Uniprocessor or Multiprocessor).

In general, the scheduler that is part of the operating system selects the process that can run.

Each program gets a certain amount of time (time slice) during which the particular program is executed. After that, it might be placed in wait queue while the other program is provided time slice for execution.